# Dold Kan correspondence for additive categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category satisfying the following property.

$$(\ast)\ \text{For every }i\colon A\rightarrow B\ \text{in }\mathcal{A}\text{ which has a left inverse, there is an isomorphism }B\cong A\oplus C\\ \text{under which }i\text{ is identified with }(id_A,0)\colon A\rightarrow A\oplus C.$$

Note that this property implies that every map $i$ as above has a cokernel in $\mathcal{A}$ (and dually for maps in $\mathcal{A}$ that admits a right inverse). Now, in Higher Algebra, Section 1.2.4, Lurie claims that

> These conditions (additivity and the ($\ast$) property - Ed.) are sufficient to construct a Dold-Kan correspondence in $\mathcal{A}$.

The way I am interpreting this statement is that, under the above hypotheses on $\mathcal{A}$, one can construct a functor $N\colon\mathcal{A}^{\Delta^{op}}\rightarrow \mathrm{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\mathcal{A})$ and show that it is a quasi-inverse to the functor $\Gamma\colon \mathrm{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\mathcal{A})\rightarrow \mathcal{A}^{\Delta^{op}}$ which appears in the ordinary Dold-Kan correspondence (for, say, abelian categories). Assuming this is what "constructing a Dold-Kan correspondence in $\mathcal{A}$" means, I do not know how to prove Lurie's statement.

Here are some naive thoughts. Given a simplicial object $X$ in $\mathcal{A}$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, one can consider the maps
$$
\delta_n:= (d_i)_{i=1}^{n} \colon X_n\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}X_{n-1}\quad\text{and}\quad \sigma_n:= (s_i)_{i=1}^{n-1}\colon \bigoplus_{i=0}^{n-1}X_{n-1}\rightarrow X_n,
$$
where the $d_i$'s and the $s_i$'s are the faces and degeneracies of $X$ respectively. Now, using the simplicial identities, we get that $\delta_n$ has a right inverse and $\sigma_n$ has a left inverse. So one can consider the kernel of $\delta_n$ and the cokernel of $\sigma_n$ in $\mathcal{A}$, thanks to $(\ast)$. The assignments $n\mapsto \ker(\delta_n)$ and $n\mapsto \mathrm{coker}(\sigma_n)$ give rise to $\mathbb{N}-$graded chain complexes $N(A)$ and $N'(A)$ in $\mathcal{A}$ respectively. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category, $N(A)$ corresponds to the description of the normalized chain complex as a subobject of the alternating face map complex (aka unnormalized chain complex), whereas $N'(A)$ corresponds to its description as a quotient of the same complex.

> **Question 1**: Are $N(A)$ and $N'(A)$ canonically isomorphic?
>
> **Question 2**: Is either of the two functors $N,N'\colon\mathcal{A}^{\Delta^{op}}\rightarrow \mathrm{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\mathcal{A})$ a quasi-inverse to $\Gamma$ as above?

References in the literature that answer either of these questions for abelian categories seem to use the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem for abelian categories at one point or another and I can't see a way to provide an element-free way around it (yet).

Any comment/help would be appreciated.

**P.S./Warning:** Lurie's claim is actually about the homotopy category of a stable infinity category $\mathcal{C}$, in the sense that he writes "$\mathcal{hC}$" where I wrote "$\mathcal{A}$" in the cited excerpt from Higher Algebra above. Now, the way the claim is phrased in Higher Algebra seems to indicate (at least to me) that what is needed to "construct a Dold-Kan correspondence" is that $\mathcal{A}$ is additive and satisfies $(\ast)$. However, if it turns out that assuming $\mathcal{A}$ to be triangulated helps in making things work out properly, I would be happy to add that assumption to the mix (in fact, a triangulated category satisfies $(\ast)$).

Comment: As an aside, I think a thing you can do is show an equivalence between the categories you get from index categories $\Delta$ and $\mathbb{N}$ after you apply the construction of linearizing them, splitting off idempotent, and adjoining direct sums.

Comment: @Hurkyl Interesting! Do you have references?

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for the comment. That seems pretty hard to do though? ($\mathbb{Z}\Delta$ has many idempotents....)

Comment: @Hanno: Unfortunately, no. :( I know something on mathoverflow talks about it, but I don't think I can find it.

Comment: @MarcoVergura: IIRC, it's supposed to look very similar to the proof that, for a simplicial abelian group, the unnormalized chain complex is the direct sum of the normalized one and the degenerate complex. I always get overwhelmed by the combinatorics, though, and never quite managed to finish working through the proof myself.

Comment: I couldn’t get that $\delta_n$ has a right inverse. How about constant simplicial abelian groups?